# Generate jQuery HTML Element with Expected Length of 1, element.length Returns 15

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The function I was trying to use wasn't working, so I tested the length selection (should be one):

```
$('header').append('<p id="ancho_ventana"></p>');
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(('p#ancho_ventana').length); //outputs "15"
});
```

Also tried with

```
var ancho = $('<p id="ancho_ventana"></p>').hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('resize',function(){
       alert(('p#ancho_ventana').length);   
    })
});
```

And the second function outputs the same. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `alert` returns the length of the string `p#ancho_ventana`, which contains 15 characters.
I think you meant:

```
alert($('p#ancho_ventana').length);
```

Comment: +1. His current line `alert('p#ancho_ventana').length);` will generate a syntax error anyway, but that was probably a typo retyping it.